# How to reuse TCP connections with .NET BigQuery API?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm streaming data into BQ with .NET API. And I noticed in Process Explorer that new TCP/IP connections are created and ended over and over again. I'm wondering if it's possible to reuse the connection and avoid big overhead of connection creation and end?

```
    public async Task InsertAsync(BaseBigQueryTable table, IList<IDictionary<string, object>> rowList, GetBqInsertIdFunction getInsert,CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (rowList.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        string tableId = table.TableId;
        IList<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> requestRows = rowList.Select(row => new TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData {Json = row,InsertId = getInsert(row)}).ToList();
        TableDataInsertAllRequest request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest { Rows = requestRows };           
        bool needCreateTable = false;
        BigqueryService bqService = null;
        try
        {
            bqService = GetBigQueryService();                
            TableDataInsertAllResponse response =
                await
                    bqService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, _account.ProjectId, table.DataSetId, tableId)
                        .ExecuteAsync(ct);               
            IList<TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrorsData> insertErrors = response.InsertErrors;
            if (insertErrors != null && insertErrors.Count > 0)
            {
                //handling errors, removed for easier reading..
            }
        }catch{
           //... removed for easier reading
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bqService != null)
                bqService.Dispose();
        }
       }

private BigqueryService GetBigQueryService()
{
   return new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
   {
       HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
       ApplicationName = _applicationName,
   });
}
```

** **Follow up** **

The answer given below seems to be the only solution to reduce http connections. however, I found using batch request on large mount of live data streaming could have some limitation. see my another questions on this: [Google API BatchRequest: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914863/google-api-batchrequest-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below link documents how to batch API calls together to reduce the number of HTTP connections your client has to make

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/batch

After batch request is issued, you can get response and parse out all involved jobids. As an alternative you can preset jobids in batch request for each and every inner request. Note: you need to make sure those jobids are unique

After that you can check what is going on with each of these jobs via jobs.get https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get

Comment: thank you! here I found an example code https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch  However, how can I get detailed response and even errors of each request from await batchRequest.ExecuteAsync() ?

Comment: ideally you should post new question :) and accept answer in this post  - if it is accepted of course

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, I will vote for it, because it helps part of my question for sure. But what people what from a Q&A is basically what to solve their problems. And in my case, I want of course to find a way that can work well. But what you suggest made me feel you potentially know the answer but just want to hold it to another question and earn reputation upon another new accepted answer. If that's the case, I don't think that's how the community should work.

Comment: I will add my thoughts in my previous answer. i asked you about posting new question because this is how I saw other (who looks like mature communicaty users) suggesting. Didnt mean to break rules

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts. To be honest, I don't know what rules are there. From my point of view, a good community focus on problems we are dealing with. Rules serves to our goals and make things reasonable and handy. I saw lots of posts here in stackoverflow that people keep building on one topic by discussions back and forth in comments and new answers. It helps to deepen peoples insight. That's the way I would support:)

Comment: added more to my original answer

Comment: I stream live data via the above API, there's no job id... but I did figure out in its call back, I can get TableDataInsertAllResponse as content where the errors should be. I'll digging into it more. thank you!